# How can i open URL in ionic application using inappbrowser?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am making an ionic application and i want to open url in system browser i have installed ionic inappbrowser plugin but i dont know how to use it can some help me with the code.

I want to open {{object.url}} in an browser.

## I am using ionic 1

HTML

```
 <body ng-app="newsapp" ng-controller="newscontroller">

<ion-pane>
  <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
    <h1 class="title">Tech Crunch</h1>
  </ion-header-bar>
  <ion-content>
  <section class="list">

   <article ng-repeat="object in news">
    <a navigate-To="{{object.url}}" class="item item-thumbnail-center">
      <img ng-src="{{object.urlToImage}}" height="100%" width="100%">
    <h2 class="nowhitespace">{{object.title}}/</h2>
    <p class="nowhitespace">{{object.description}}</p>
    <h6><i>Published At</i> {{object.publishedAt}}</h6>

     </a>

   </article> 
   
  </section>
  <ion-infinite-scroll on-infinite="loadMore()" distance="1%">
  </ion-infinite-scroll>

      </ion-content>
    </ion-pane>u
    </body>
```

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('newsapp', ['ionic']);

  .directive("navigateTo",function($ionicGesture){

 return{
restrict: 'A',
 link:function($scope,$element,$attr){

var tapharndle = function(e){
  var inAppBrowser = window.open{encodeURI{$attr.navigateTo},'_blank','location=yes','toolbar=yes'};
};
var tapGesture = $ionicGesture.on{'tap',tapharndle,$element};

    }
   }
   })
   
  $http({
      method: "GET",
        url: "https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=techcrunch& 
        sortBy=latest&   ``apiKey=90b77760d33d4c76af4c6c53862c9e72"
      }) .then(function(newsdata){
      angular.forEach(newsdata.data.articles, function(newsarticle) {
   $scope.news.push(newsarticle);

    });
     $scope.lastarticleID= newsdata.data.lastID;
    //$scope.news =newsdata.data.articles;
    console.log(newsdata);
  } )
    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the latest [$cordovaInAppBrowser](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/inAppBrowser/) Plugin, which provides a web browser view. It could be used to open images, access web pages, and open PDF files.

Use **`cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser`** command from console to add the plugin.

The following configuration of **location** sets the visibility of URL:

```
  var defaultOptions = {
    location: 'no',
    clearcache: 'no',
    toolbar: 'no'
  };
```

Further instructions are provided on the page of URL given.

Comment: I dont understand it can u explain

Comment: Muhammad i dont understand that,that is why i asked you here

Comment: Just inject the dependency and use document.addEventListener, as explained on http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/inAppBrowser/